# how to optimize algoia indexing to improve user experience

Tags: php, node.js, search, algolia

I want to implement ALGOLIA search in my php web application
for that i have to index my records in algolia server like if a user registered in my application i have to insert its data not only in my db but also in algolia server 
Due to that user will face little leg in application may be its of few second or may be in microsecond but it counts

so i want any alternative(background processing) of it so that algolia indexing dint effect the user experience

I am thinking about `nodejs` is it possible to fire event in node js to update indexing on algolia server and respond to user without waiting for algolia response (am new bee to nodejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, indexing is asynchronous, so you shouldn't need to wait that a record get indexed. Whenever a user adds something new to your application, 1/ save it your DB, then 2/ **push it to Algolia without using the waitTask method**. The new record will then be accessible as a search results a few milliseconds / seconds after it gets added to the index.

In that way, won't have any impact on your application performance and user-experience.

Comment: is it fruitful if we go with background indexing with nodejs

Comment: Sure, you can go with background indexing using nodejs, but you can also do the same using PHP. Indexing object as soon as they get saved in you DB is definitely a good practice. Just make sure to only call the addObject method without calling waitTask afterward, and it should do what you're looking for.